# AWS CLI doesn't show output

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cli

I'm running into a weird situation where the aws cli doesn't show output at all. I tried running bad commands and it would show the expected error message but when I run a valid command such as: `aws s3api list-buckets --profile prod` it doesn't show anything, it just starts new line.

Comment: do you have `less` command installed on your local system and also make sure you are using latest version of aws cli

Comment: For more information about what @JatinMehrotra is suggesting, see: [Using AWS CLI pagination options - AWS Command Line Interface](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/cli-usage-pagination.html)

Comment: Are there buckets to list? Permission issue?